# How to read configuration file in EAR from the jar with in it

Tags: java, jar, configuration-files, weblogic12c, ear

I have a configuration file in my jar file, I was reading it with `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream()` method using relative path. But when I was trying to use weblogic deployment plan to modify the configuration file when deploying it. It seems there is no way to find this file if it is in the jar.

Now I took it out from the jar and put this file inside the META-INF folder of the EAR file so that weblogic deployment plan can read it. But my problem is, I don't know how can I still read this file from my java code of this jar file. Is there any way to read the file in EAR from the jar? Thanks.

Comment: What version of JSE and JEE are you using.  Probably does not matter, but good to note.

Comment: I am using java 1.8